# Is it safe to send my id photo for verification

Tags: identity-theft

Is it safe to send my ID photo and me holding my ID photo to a site(BitSkins). My intetions were to buy some skins for games, but they asked for verification so can they missuse my identity ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Website asks for my identification card - Is it safe?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/147243/website-asks-for-my-identification-card-is-it-safe), [Is it standard practice to ask a customer to send a photo of their credit card to confirm their identity?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18240/is-it-standard-practice-to-ask-a-customer-to-send-a-photo-of-their-credit-card-t) and [several more](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Asecurity.stackexchange.com+send+photo+id).

Comment: Why would they need you ID for? They just need your money. By paying with VISA/MasterCard you do not need to provide your ID for the payment to be successful (you can provide a pseudonym instead of your real name). Requiring a photo is a red flag.